# IE Compatibility view causes Javascript menu to render backwards off the screen

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer

Is there a way to get a javascript menu to render properly when opened in IE in compatibility view? The underlying issue this company's application was built using old school tables and some sporadic CSS circa CSS 2. As a result, employees are having to run the site in IE with compatibility mode on to get queried notes to display right, otherwise they will run off the screen; forcing them to scroll off to the right. Likewise there are other elements of the site which they have to open in Chrome because of IE rendering issues.

When compatibility mode is off in IE, the menu displays properly as shown below:
Displays properly in Chrome as well.
[image]

But when in compatibility mode:

[image]
[image]

Menu turns blue and tries to open off the screen to the left.

Is there a known fix to this issue.

**Code:**

```
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery- 
ui.min.js"></script>
<!---<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />--->
<script>
$(function() {
$("#menu" ).menu();
});


$(function() {
$(document ).tooltip();

});

function Refresh() {
child.location.reload(true);
}
</script>
<style>
    a{
        font-family:Arial;          
    }

#MainMenu
{
    background-color:"#58B0EB";
}
.ui-menu { width: 270px;
            font: Arial;
            font-size: small;                       
            }

 .ui-tooltip {
    background-image: none;
    background-color: #f7f792; 
    display: inline-block;
    font: Verdana;
    font-size:x-small;  
  }

</style>
</head>
<body>

<cfset User_Id=session.ft_user_id>  
<cfinvoke component="cfc.MainMenu" method="GetMenuHead" 
returnvariable="GetMenuHeadRet"> 
    <cfinvokeargument name="User_Id" value="#User_Id#"/>
</cfinvoke>

<ul id="menu">
    <li>            
        <a id="MainMenu" href="#">Reports and tools</a>
        <ul>
        <cfloop query="GetMenuHeadRet">
            <cfif GetMenuHeadRet.recordcount gt 0>
            <li style="background-color:#E6E6E6;">
                <cfoutput><a href="##">#Description#</a></cfoutput>
                <cfinvoke component="cfc.MainMenu"  method="GetMenuItem" 
        returnvariable="GetMenuItemRet">
                    <cfinvokeargument name="menukey" value="#ID#"/>
                    <cfinvokeargument name="User_Id" value="#User_Id#"/>
                </cfinvoke>

                <ul>
                    <cfif GetMenuItemRet.recordcount gt 0>
                        <cfloop query="GetMenuItemRet">                                                 
                                <cfoutput><li><a title="#report_Desc#" 
      onClick="Refresh();" href="#URL#?uid="#User_Id# 
      target="_blank">#Report_Name#</a></li></cfoutput>
                        </cfloop>
                    </cfif>
                </ul>
            </li>
            </cfif>
        </cfloop>
      </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is recommended you provide a code example when asking these kinds of questions (a quick jsfiddle will do fine). Otherwise, have a look at this handy chart to see what CSS selectors are available in IE7 http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selectors/

Comment: I checked the chart and have tried a couple of different things but to no avail. Ideally I would like to be able to not have to use the compatibility view but unfortunately no one is addressing the underlying issue in the site forcing the use of compatibility mode to make the other part of the site function decently while causing my CSS3/HTML5 menu to render the wrong direction.

Comment: You can try `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` ... for absolute assurance, make this the first tag in the `<head>`